# calculate the percentage between two numbers inside HTML table TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, percentage

My complete example is here in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/03b5ywpp/)

I have a HTML table with few values in it. I want to find the Percentage in each `tr` based on the `td` values in it and have to append the resulted value at the end of each `tr`.

My jQuery code

```
$('tr').each (function() {
    var frstCol = $(this).find('.combat').text();
    var seCol = $(this).find('.ac_yeild').text(); 
    var result = parseInt(frstCol) * 100 / parseInt(seCol);
    console.log(result);
    $('.res').text(result);
});
```

How do i calculate the percentage for first and second column and put it back in my `result` column for each `tr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(this).find('.res').text(result);//this will replace only specific result class
```

Instead of

```
$('.res').text(result);//this is replacing all values of res class with new value
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/03b5ywpp/2/)

> **Note:** You are getting **NAN** value because of td contain **'--'** **Not a Number**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the value of result for each seperate column:

```
  $('tr').each (function() {
            var frstCol = $(this).find('.combat').text();
            var seCol = $(this).find('.ac_yeild').text(); 
           alert(frstCol)

               var result = (parseInt(frstCol) / parseInt(seCol))* 100 ;
               console.log(result);
               if(isNaN(result))
                 $(this).find('.res').text(0);
               else
                 $(this).find('.res').text(result);



        });
```

Comment: Thanks... But is this way of determining percentage between two numbers is right? i found this thread for calculating the percentage btw two numbers. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799055/calculate-percentage-saved-between-two-numbers](http://example.com)