# Growth calculation NaN with 0 value

Tags: php

I try to calculate growth but if I have like last month value zero then it gives me:

> 'NaN'

All these values gives me 'NaN':

Examples what can be my values:

```
var_dump((($this_month - $last_month) / $last_month) * 100);
var_dump(((0 - 0) / 0) * 100);
var_dump(((5 - 0) / 0) * 100); //this should be 100% not 'NaN'
```

Doing something wrong or my math calculation is wrong?

I used this first accepted answer (The percentage increase ...):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799055/calculate-percentage-saved-between-two-numbers
```

I have negative percentages also if last month was successful and current month isnt successful.

Comment: Division by 0 produces NaN. Why do you think it should be 100%?

Comment: Yes, use error reporting and you would see https://3v4l.org/otoLh

Comment: @AbraCadaver So I have to use switch statements or if statements checking if `$last_month` is 0?

Comment: Yes division by 0 is undefined in math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x/0` is undefined, no matter what `x` is.

If your `$last_month` == 0, you're [dividing by zero](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/dividing-by-zero.html), which mathematically is undefined.

`NaN` stands for "Not a Number", i.e. undefined.

The response your code is giving you is correct.

Comment: What is best way to create month sale growth? using if or switch statements? because you're right about that.

Comment: This is the correct answer by the way. A percentage increase doesn't make sense. If sales increase from $0 to $150, what percentage increase is that? `$0 * 2000% = $0`, `$0 * 15% = $0`. It's up to you to decide how you want to represent an undefined value.

Comment: https://sciencing.com/calculate-percentage-monthly-growth-8124035.html I used this for creating that calculation...

Comment: Because I have sales and users what counts how many purchases and how many users registered.

Comment: That calculation doesn't work if your last month's sales were 0 for the reasons explained in my answer. You should mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: If it doesnt work with 0 maybe explain how it should work.

Comment: It works perfectly with 0. The question `x/0` doesn't make sense, you can't divide a pizza into 0 pieces. Have a read of [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/5659) on the Maths Educators Stack Exchange. The correct answer is `undefined` or `NaN`.

Comment: asking php function how to do it?

Comment: Your formula is correct, and it is giving you a correct result. Your code doesn't have a problem, you're just dividing by zero.

Comment: Yes but there must be some check point what checks if divider is negative or 0...

Comment: Are you looking for `if($last_month === 0)`?